# Why do I get a different output from same input using GradientBoostingRegressor of scikit-learn?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

For example:

```
params = {'n_estimators': 200, "max_depth": 4, 'subsample': 1, 'learning_rate': 0.1}
boost = ensemble.GradientBoostingRegressor(**params)
ghostBoost = ensemble.GradientBoostingRegressor(**params)

...

boost.fit(x, y)
ghostBoost.fit(x, y)

...

predictionA = boost.predict(features)
predictionB = ghostBoost.predict(features)
```

`boost` and `ghostBoost` are exact the same but `predictionA` does not equal to `predictionB`, why is this happening?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try fixing the `random_state` constructor parameter for both models to the same value. The decision tree building process is randomized as each node considers `max_features` drawn at random (<del>with replacement</del> without replacement) from the available features.

Edit: the feature sampling is done without replacement. When `max_features=None` (the default) all features are evaluated, however the ordering changes which can have an impact when `max_depth` is not `None` and that the target variable has non-unique values leading to tied best feature splits.

Comment: Thanks a lot mate! I forced `random_state` = 1, and now all results are consistent, would this affect performance in any way?

Comment: I just noticed when the order of input samples is changed, the results, which are supposed to be the same, are actually different, could you please also give some opinion on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22170677/how-come-the-output-is-different-when-the-order-of-input-samples-is-changedgra ?

Comment: The results are not supposed to be the same if you do not fix the random_state and have tied target values: tie-breaking is impacted by the ordering of the samples.

Comment: I believe I've fixed `random_state = 1`, so basically if the target values are very close, the order of the input samples will definitely impact the results, right?